# How to make a search date field on Rails to find items on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have:

```
def index
     @sheets = Sheet.where(user_id: current_user)
end
```

And I want it to make it:

```
 if params[:search]
    @sheets = Sheet.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @sheets = Sheet.all.order("created_at DESC")
 end
```

But I want the field on my view to be a DATE field with a dropdown calendar to make it easier for users to search sheets, how can I do this? I already looked at: http://www.rymcmahon.com/articles/2

Comment: `search` function does not exist, you have to use `where` clause

Comment: would Sheets.where(created_at: :search) work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `params[:search]` a single date? 
Use [TimeZone.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326276/how-to-make-a-search-date-field-on-rails-to-find-items-on-database#comment77619142_45326276) to parse your date string into an actual date.

If so, your [where code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326276/how-to-make-a-search-date-field-on-rails-to-find-items-on-database#comment77619142_45326276) is fine with a slight modification:

```
Sheets.where(created_at: Time.zone.parse(params[:search]))
```

But this would literally only return sheets who's created_at time is exactly the same as the entered time (to the second). So, is it really `params[:start_date]` & `params[:end_date]`? At least then you could return all sheets where created_at is within a range of dates:

```
Sheets.where( created_at: Time.zone.parse(params[:start_date])..Time.zone.parse(params[:end_date]) )
```